# What are the different target types in EDE?

Tags: emacs, cedet

`M-x ede-new-target` asks for a target type, and while the target types are sort of self explanatory, it's not 100% clear to me how to use them. For example I assume a "program" target is for code files, but what about miscellaneous? The example in the EDE manual uses it for header files, but can something else be put in there? What is the sharedobject target for? Etc etc.

There doesn't seem to be any good documentation of this anywhere, so can somone please describe what these target types are for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some description there is in info documentation, other you can see in source code...
Here is a list of current targets, it vary depending on project type:

- `archive` - object code archive/static library
- `auxiliary` - handles auxiliary files in project - README, *.txt, etc.
- `emacs lisp` - compiles Emacs Lisp code
- `emacs lisp autoloads` - target to create file with Elisp autoloads
- `info` - handles texinfo files
- `miscellaneous` - target that allows user to compile other parts of project, using user-provided `Makefile`
- `program` - builds executable program
- `scheme` - target to handle Scheme (guile) source code
- `semantic grammar` - target to correctly build Semantic's grammar files, both for Wisent & Bovine. This target is defined in Semantic, not in EDE
- `sharedobject` - target to build shared libraries